# Instructions layout for Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I was looking into laying out some instructions on top of one of my applications like SoundHound does in one of their latest updates: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rziRo.png

How is something like this achieved? Is this some sort of layout over another layout? Or a "dialog box" in a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a frame layout with two children. The first would be the standard layout for the activity. The second would contain image views that display the help bubbles in the appropriate locations.

For more information see this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#framelayout

Here is nice simple example: http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/3/

Comment: Thanks for the help, will look more into the example once I go to implement it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) with some elements having negative margins. They will overlap over other elements.